# Firebase Firestore - Common function for queries but with different outcomes

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'll try to explain myself the best I can.

What I'm trying to do is to set a common function which I can pass the name of the collection and do something with that. The problem is that since it is an asynchronous request I can't just do `var a = getFirestoreData();` so i'll have to use this piece of code over and over again:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
myCollection = 'SomeRandomCollectionName';

//Repetitive piece of code
db.collection(myCollection).get().then((snapshot) => {
    var dataFromCollection = [];
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        dataFromCollection.push(doc.data());
    })
    //TODO -> Do something with that data.
});
```

I want to be able to do different things with different collections with that same function (only one collection each time).

Basically what I want is something like a **Utils** class and use it for example:

```
Utils.getUsers("users");
Utils.getUsersAndUpdate("users", fieldToUpdate, dataToInsert);
```

Both of those functions use that same previous piece of code but with different continuity. How do I do this taking into account that it is an asynchronous request?

This is kind of a solution I made but it lacks the possibility to add parameters to the `targetFunction` since the amount of parameters each function takes may vary.

```
function getFromDatabaseToFunction(targetFunction, collection){
    db.collection(collection).get().then((snapshot) => {
       var dataToTargetFunction = [];
       snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
           dataToTargetFunction.push(doc.data());
       })
        targetFunction(dataToTargetFunction);
    })
}
```

P.S. This may likely be a duplicate but since I don't know what to search for I can't say for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, the completion or failure of an asynchronous function is managed with a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). In your case, you can simply return a promise from `getFromDatabaseToFunction` and chain new actions with `then()`:

```
function getFromDatabase(collection){
    return db.collection(collection).get().then((snapshot) => {
       var result = [];
       snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
           result.push(doc.data());
       });
       return result;
    });
}
```

Here is how to use it:

```
var targetFunction = ...;

getFromDatabase("collectionName").then(collectionData => {
    // do whatever you want with 'targetFunction' and 'collectionData'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Build out a `.promise` like:

```
function fetchCollection(collectionPath){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var ref = firebase.firestore().collection(collectionPath);
    ref.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      resolve(querySnapshot);
    }).catch(function (error) {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
```

then use it like:

```
fetchCollection("users").then(function (querySnapshot) {
...
});
```